# Include some javascript code in HEAD on WooCommerce Order received

Tags: javascript, php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, gtag.js

Goal: I need to include an event snippet for specific tracking on the Woocommerce Order Confirmation page (the page immediately following a purchase). I must pass `order_id`, `currency` and `total` to the tracker. Here is the code I've written:

```
function wh_CustomReadOrder($order_id)
{
    //getting order object
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    echo  "<script> gtag('event', 'conversion', { 'send_to': 'AW-995109926/CWeECK-epPYBEKbYwNoD', 'value': '".$order->get_total()."', 'currency': '".$order->currency."', 'transaction_id': '".$order_id."' }); </script>";
}
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'wh_CustomReadOrder');
```

This includes the code correctly on the page and passes the relevant info to the tracker. But this code does not appear in the `<head>` of the page; it appears in the body.
Per instructions this code must be placed in the `<head>`.

I have not found a snippet plugin that allows for this kind of control.
Is there another way I can achieve this?

If I were to include this code on all pages in the `<head>` but wrap it in an `if` statement that checks for the url, `/checkout/order-received/{order-id}/` and fires if true, is that possible or there another way?

Comment: There may be an issue with passing `order_id`, `currency` and `total` if in `<head>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following to inject your Javascript code in the head on "Order received" page:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wc_custom_redirect_after_purchase' );
function wc_custom_redirect_after_purchase() {
    if ( ! is_wc_endpoint_url('order-received') ) return;
    global $wp;

    // If order_id is defined
    if ( isset($wp->query_vars['order-received']) && absint($wp->query_vars['order-received']) > 0 ) :

    $order_id       = absint($wp->query_vars['order-received']); // The order ID
    $order          = wc_get_order($order_id ); // The WC_Order object
    
    $send_to        = 'AW-995109926/CWeECK-epPYBEKbYwNoD';
    $transaction_id = empty($order->get_transaction_id()) ? $order_id : $order->get_transaction_id(); // The transaction ID
    
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    gtag('event', 'conversion', {
        'send_to'       : '<?php echo $send_to; ?>', 
        'value'         : '<?php echo $order->get_total(); ?>', 
        'currency'      : '<?php echo $order->get_currency(); ?>', 
        'transaction_id': '<?php echo $transaction_id; ?>' 
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should work.